# Hbase slave's HReginServer can not start

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

When I start my HBase , the HReginServer and HMaster of my master machine start successful , but the slaves HReginServer can not start

my hadoop version is 2.8.0 , hbase version is 1.2.6 , zookeeper version is 3.4.9

and my hbase-site.xml is :

```
<property>
     <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
     <value>hdfs://hadoop:9000/hbase</value>
</property>
<property>
     <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
     <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
     <name>hbase.master</name>
     <value>60000</value>
</property>
<property>
     <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
     <value>/usr/local/hbase/zoodata</value>
</property>

<property>
     <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
     <value>hadoop,slave03,slave02</value>
</property>
<property>
     <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
     <value>2181</value>
</property>
<property>
     <name>hbase.regionserver.port</name>
     <value>60020</value>
</property>
```

and regionservers is :

```
hadoop
slave03
slave02
```

here is the error message

```
2017-06-16 15:09:34,730 ERROR [main] 
regionserver.HRegionServerCommandLine: Region server exiting
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed construction of Regionserver: class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.constructRegionServer(HRegionServer.java:2682)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServerCommandLine.start(HRegionServerCommandLine.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServerCommandLine.run(HRegionServerCommandLine.java:87)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.main(HRegionServer.java:2697)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.constructRegionServer(HRegionServer.java:2680)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Problem binding to slave02/119.29.83.97:60020 : Cannot assign requested address. To switch ports use the 'hbase.regionserver.port' configuration property.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.<init>(RSRpcServices.java:938)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.createRpcServices(HRegionServer.java:647)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.<init>(HRegionServer.java:531)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.bind(RpcServer.java:2592)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer$Listener.<init>(RpcServer.java:585)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.<init>(RpcServer.java:2045)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.<init>(RSRpcServices.java:930)
    ... 12 more

I hope some help , thank you so much !
```

Comment: That error typically means that some other application is already running on the port you are trying to use. `netstat -alp | grep 60020` to see what else is running there.

Comment: Thank you for replying . Because this cloud server using EIP , and when I chose another cloud service merchant , it works .